# PHP JSON - Result

Tags: php, json

I've a MySQL Database (friendships-id,user_one,user_two) and i'll get this result:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "message": "OK",
    "friends": [
        "value": "idfromuser"
    ]
}
```

but i get this:

```
{"success":1,"message":"OK","friends":{"1":"1"}}
```

what is wrong?

```
$qry = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");
$result = $qry->execute(array(":username" => $_POST["username"]));
if($qry->rowCount()) {
    $row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "OK";
    $qry = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM friendships WHERE user_one = :userid OR user_two = :userid LIMIT 1");
    $result = $qry->execute(array(":userid" => $row["id"]));
    while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $response["friends"][$row["id"]] = $row["id"];
    }
}
die(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: `[$row["id"]] = $row["id"]`... it's exactly the result I'd expect from that line...

Comment: Don't you want $response["friends"]["value"] = $row["id"];?

Comment: `$response["friends"][$row["id"]]` => `$response["friends"]["value"]` ? But you will get only one `idfromuser`. It's unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: oh i've limit 1. its work now :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
$response["friends"][$row["id"]] = $row["id"];
```

Key and value both are `$row["id"];`

in left side rather than id use value.